Cosmological constant and gravitational lensing
The cosmological constant, $\Lambda$, leads to a uniform positive energy throughout the universe. It would lead to a more positive Ricci Scalar.
The question is whether it should lead to slowing down of the measured speed of light? Additionally, I am wondering whether it will lead to gravitational lensing.
Since, the positive energy is uniform, intuitively it should not lead to gravitational lensing. Is this correct?

These are both independently really good questions - does $\Lambda$ affect speed of light and does $\Lambda$ cause G-lensing - but they can't both be in the same post.

@controlgroup - since gravitational lensing goes hand in hand with a shapirodelayed speed of light both questions are related and can therefore be stated in on posting. The reason why one shall not ask too many questions in one posting is to avoid multiple screen long novels, but that is clearly not the case here.


Angela asked: "The question is whether it should lead to slowing down of the measured speed of light?"

In the local neighbourhood of an observer the speed of light is c, but farther away it is not.

Angela asked: "Since, the positive energy is uniform, intuitively it should not lead to gravitational lensing. Is this correct?"

It leads to uniform gravitational lensing, the observed angular size of an object of a given size at a given distance is different than it would be in flat spacetime.

You might add that those answers (which are correct!) do account for the expansion caused by the cosmological constant.

@yukterez the cosmological constant is all around uniformly. Lensing should be possible, only if there is some non-homogenity. If space is filled uniformly with a refractive medium, there should be no lensing. Similarly on speed of light. How would we ever know what happens if there is no cosmological constant.

@Angela - 1) if your definition of lensing is limited to distortion then no, but if the definition includes magnification then yes. 2) the last scattering surface whos light reaches us today was 0.04 billion lightyears away when its light was emitted and is 46 billion lightyears away when the light is received, while the light itself travelled for 14 billion years, which is different than in would have been in flat spacetime where we have 1 lightyear per year.

@Yukterez 1) Even for magnification. As a analogy, if the observer and the source are both inside a swimming pool, there should be no magnification or distortion. Ultimately, there should be a variation in the speed of light for light to bend.  2) Are you referring to inflation due to the cosmological constant?
